# LUA Time format string split

Tags: string, split, lua

I've been hurting my head for the past week to get this working.
I"m trying to split a timecode format string to input into a table.
The string format I'm looking to split is: 00:00:00.00 (HH:MM:SS.FRAME)

I've tried using this string split:

```
function split(s, delimiter)
    result = {};
    for match in (s..delimiter):gmatch("(.-)"..delimiter) do
        table.insert(result, match);
    end
    return result;
end

s = split("10:00:00.00",':')

for key, value in pairs(s) do
    print(key..'='..value)
end
```

Which returns

```
1=10
2=00
3=00.00
```

Now I cannot get my head around splitting that last result into two different lines Is it not possible to capture the delimiter ' . ' to split a string?

Swapping the arguments to

```
s = split("10.00.00.00",'.')
```

results in

```
1=
2=
3=
4=
5=
6=
7=
8=
9=
10=
11=
12=
```

It's my first post on stackoverflow, please be gentle :)
Huge thanks to anyone who can point me in any kind of direction to make this work.. it's for a school project :)

Comment: You can use the escape `%` for the magic characters `( ) . % + - * ? [ ^ $` maybe so:   `:gmatch("(.-)%"..delimiter)`

Comment: I'm doing tests on this new version:
    a,b,c,d = s:match("(.+):(.+):(.+)%.(.+)")